# ReactJS (JSX) syntax highlighting in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs

I'm reading about "built-in support of jsx syntax in VS 2015", but can't find it. Is it hidden in settings of IDE, or I need to install some extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

React.js Starter Kit:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d65d6b29-6dd7-4100-81b1-609e5afce356

**Support for native jsx (update 1 to VS2015):**
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx

Comment: Just wanted to try it out. Started with statement import React from 'react' and got intellisense errors. What dissapointing experience.

Comment: visualstudio.com link is giving me a 403.  Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not a direct fix to your problem, you could try out http://code.visualstudio.com/. Visual studio has all kinds of problems with these new web dev tools. Another example is the [npm - not installed](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudio2015FixingDependenciesNpmNotInstalledFromFseventsWithNodeOnWindows.aspx) issue.